# Grid action with ajax not working

Tags: magento-1.7, magento-1.8, ce-1.7.0.2

I added a tab to customer edit in admin magento, it's a grid. I used

```
$this->setUseAjax(true);
```

but when i filter, it's just loading and not show results. I have getGridUrl() in Custom.php:

```
public function getGridUrl()
    {
        return $this->getUrl('*/*/grid', array('_current'=> true));
    }
```

And i have controller with grid action:

```
public function gridAction()
    {
        $this->loadLayout();
        $this->getResponse()->setBody(
            $this->getLayout()->createBlock('mymodule/adminhtml_customer_edit_tab_custom')->toHtml()
        );
    }
```

but still not filter

Comment: What is the response from the ajax call? If you see the loading gif, there must be a response.

Comment: yeah, it just loading with loading gif, and response list customers from page manage customers, but it still loading and loading

Comment: If this is a new tab in the customer edit form then you shouldn't use `'*/*/grid'` as your grid url. This will make the request to the customer admin controller. Put your own controller in there. Something like `'*/mycontroller/grid'`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yeah, i found solution following by marius's hint. My controller

Mymodule/controllers/Adminhtml/TestController.php

```
<?php

class Myextension_Mymodule_Adminhtml_TestController{

    public function gridAction()
    {
        $this->loadLayout();
        $this->getResponse()->setBody(
            $this->getLayout()->createBlock('mymodule/adminhtml_customer_edit_tab_custom')->toHtml()
        );
    }
}
```

My config.xml:

```
<admin>
 <routers>
    <adminhtml>
       <args>
        <modules>
          <myextension_mymodule before="Mage_Adminhtml">Myextension_Mymodule_Adminhtml</myextension_mymodule>
        </modules>
       </args>
    </adminhtml>
 </routers>
</admin>
```

Change

```
public function getGridUrl()
    {
        return $this->getUrl('*/*/grid', array('_current'=> true));
    }
```

To

```
public function getGridUrl()
        {
            return $this->getUrl('*/test/grid', array('_current'=> true));
        }
```